# OR en C# en estructura de repeticion IF

Tags: c#

Hola quisiera saber como restringir una entrada de usuario a dos posibles solicitudes con una sentencia `if`, esto sin tener que anidar las dos posibilidades, por ejemplo:

```
IF(dato==xx) o (dato==XX)
```

No me permite el uso del operador `|`,desconozco cual seria la sintaxis o la lógica correcta al uso de dicho operador

Gracias

Comment: Creo que [ésto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158580/what-is-the-or-operator-in-an-if-statement) puede servirte

Comment: En [tag:C#] la sintaxis de la compuerta OR es `||` por ejemplo `if(1 == 1 || 1<2)`, te recomiendo que [leas este artículo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) donde explica el uso de todos los operadores lógicos dentro de C#

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal me parece que tu comentario amerita estar como respuesta.

Comment: @CamiloBernal ahora lo redacto :D

Comment: Saludos Andromeda, este enlace te ayudará: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/

Answer (score 3):

Dentro de [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), el operador lógico [or](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerta_OR) es

```
||
```

Por lo que en una condición se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
if(numero == 1 || numero > 5)
{
     //En caso de ser válida la condición.
}
```

En el ejemplo `numero` es una variable numérica.

La condición se cumplirá, sólo si `numero` vale `1` **`O`** `numero` es mayor que `5`

Sería muy recomendable leer [este artículo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) de la documentación de Microsoft, donde se explica detalladamente el uso de todos los operadores lógicos dentro de C#